# Audio is not playing in html

Tags: html, audio, web, pug

I have music stored in a separate folder that I am trying to play, however the music won't play. Any idea why? All help is appreciated and thanks in advance. Also trying to do the same thing in Jade so if you guys tell me the code for that, it would be great too!

```
<body>
    <li>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="./songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
         </audio>
    </li>
<body>
```

Path to html file :

> /User/Desktop/music-app/views/test.html

Path to audio file:

> /User/Desktop/music-app/songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3

Comment: also trying to work with m4a, which doesnt seem to be working either

Comment: did you check if the path is correct? Eg. if it is loaded in the network section of your developer tool (F12)

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/sq2ev5vaa74eamq/Screenshot%202015-12-30%2014.15.51.png?dl=0 . That is my directory view, is there anything wrong?

Comment: @beekeeper, is the audio file in the same folder as the HTML file?

Comment: @PhiterFernandes no it isn't, its in a separate folder

Comment: Paste into your question the path to the HTML file and the path to the audio file, please

Comment: @PhiterFernandes added the path, sorry for not including it earlier

Comment: Try this: `<source src="../songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3" type="audio/mp3">`

Comment: it works! thank you so much to for the help. Any reason as to why ./ didn't work? that should normally take you up 1 directory right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can dynamically generate an audio player, I believe your problem is getting the correct path to your mp3. Use this code and change the src value on line 6.
When in doubt, use the absolute path or in your case a relative path of `../songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3`

```js
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
var source = document.createElement('source');
var media = document.getElementById('media');
media.appendChild(audio);
audio.appendChild(source);
source.setAttribute('src', 'https://glpro.s3.amazonaws.com/_util/smpte/111.mp3');
source.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mpeg');
audio.setAttribute('controls', 'controls');
```

```html
<section id="media"></section>
```

Comment: currently I'm not using any javascript code for my front end, is there any way to do it without it?

Comment: Sure the way your doing it is fine, just remember that the `type=audio/mpeg` for mp3. and for `src`, try `../songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3`

Comment: If that works for you, give Rahul Kumar the accept and give me an upvote ;)

Comment: I tried earlier, Im too new for that :( another quick question, how do I play .m4a files?

Comment: No worries, just do exactly what your'e doing now but use `type="audio/mp4"` Just thinking you could load both mp3 and m4a just use separate `<source>` elements. It makes sense if they are the same song with different file extensions. That's more fore browser compatibility, but I believe mp3 is pretty much universal.

Comment: This example doesn't make any sound on my chrome (94.0.4606.81 (Official Build) (x86_64), macos 11.6)...

Answer (score 4):

Try this.. It works..

Add `..` to goto previous directory and use `type="audio/mpeg"`

```
<body>
    <li>
        <audio controls>
            <source src="../songs/Remember-The-Name.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
         </audio>
    </li>
<body>
```

Comment: Same problem as before, It brings up the player, however the player doesnt work

Comment: His solution should work, considering the file paths.

Comment: Yea I had a name error when I tried his plan the first time, it does work. I was just being dumb :(

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you link your audio correctly.
That is what helped me.

Comment: This should be a comment